# how to update model for updated database table on an online server

Tags: cakephp

How to update model of a database table on online server.

I added one column to database table on server

I am unable to save data to it through api might be because its model is not baked.

It's a cake php project.

Comment: Did you clear the model cache?

Comment: How to clear the model cache.

Comment: Specifically which version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: If I understand correctly your question, you should delete what's in the cakephp tmp folder (that's where the cache is)

Comment: My database is uploaded on online server. All folders are online.  I Donot have on my PC.  I picked up this midway which has been developed by someone else.  I know less about php MVC.  Project is working except for the column that I added to one table.  May be model updations are required , but how to do that.

Comment: And specifically which version of CakePHP are you using?

Answer (score 0):

in terminal run:

```
 1. bin/cake version
 2. bin/cake cache clear_all
```

if you using **CakePHP version 3.x** then in your Entity/YourEnityNameHere.php add to `$_accessible` array your new colums.

Comment: The database is on panel hoisting and built under PhpMyAdmin , I added one column into the already running project.  This new field is not accessible.  Please tell what to do

Comment: "This new field is not accessible." edit your Entity and add new filed to list and clear cache